# ASP.NET 5 / EF7 tags incorrectly synonymized

Tags: support, retag-request

The tag synonyms created as per [What will become of [asp.net-5] and [entity-framework-7] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315077/what-will-become-of-asp-net-5-and-entity-framework-7-tags) are incorrect. Instead of creating synonyms, a tag rename needs to be done.

The [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) and [asp.net-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-vnext) tags need to remain as they were, available for new questions. What needs to happen instead is that all questions that were tagged as [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) need to have that tag removed and have a new [asp.net-core-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1) tag added (note: there needs to be a `-1` suffix to indicate the version, much like existing ASP.NET questions are generally versioned, unless they are version agnostic).

There could conceivably be a *new* product called ASP.NET 5 and Entity Framework 7, which would be the natural successors to ASP.NET 4 and Entity Framework 6. With the current synonyms this becomes impossible because questions would be erroneously re-tagged due to the synonyms.

The correct mappings are:

- Questions that were tagged as [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) need to change to [asp.net-core-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1)
- Questions that were tagged as [asp.net-mvc-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-6) need to change to [asp.net-core-mvc-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc-1)
- Questions that were tagged as [entity-framework-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-7) need to change to [ef-core-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-1) (note the shortened name, which is necessary because of tag length limits on SE, and there will certainly be longer tags such as [efcore-1-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efcore-1-migrations) etc. in the future)
- Lastly, all the recently created tag synonyms need to be deleted (seen in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms by searching for `asp.net` and `entity-framework`)

Note: I'm the engineering manager at Microsoft for ASP.NET and Entity Framework.

Note 2: It's worth noting that this would prevent the exact problem that was pointed out to me just over a year ago in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276926/make-asp-net-vnext-a-synonym-for-asp-net-5 (deleted by me) where I asked to rename [asp.net-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-vnext) to [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) and was rejected for exactly the reasons I mention here. The two tags are *not* synonyms, it's a rename.

Comment: [I tried to bloody tell them, but they wouldn't listen.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315197/1228)  Also, you guys rename stuff way too damn often.  This one was reasonable, but most of the time stahp.

Comment: @Will yup I already upvoted your various answers and comments :( Unfortunately I didn't see the two previous threads about this until a colleague mentioned it to me a few hours ago.

Comment: The tags *were* renamed, and synonyms were added for the transitioning phase in which people will consider ASP.NET 5 a synonym for ASP.NET Core. Otherwise we would just continue seeing new ASP.NET 5 tags now. And I disagree with this overzealous versioning of those tags. Most things on Stack Overflow work fine without explicit versions, and unless I see it, I highly doubt that the major versions will introduce that big breaking changes that tagging them without a version would be any problem. And even with versions, we would still have version-less tags.

Comment: Related: [Should there generally be only one tag for a language, rather than multiple (especially minor) versions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299598/should-there-generally-be-only-one-tag-for-a-language-rather-than-multiple-esp), and [Should I tag questions C++11 if they refer to the C++11 standard but not new features?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271812/should-i-tag-questions-c11-if-they-refer-to-the-c11-standard-but-not-new-fea)

Comment: @poke on versioning and version-specific tags I can certainly agree with that. Regarding the synonyms, when would the synonym entry be deleted?

Comment: @Eilon Tag synonyms can be requested to be removed at any point, so I would say let’s remove them, when they are no longer needed, that is when the new names can stand on their own feet (maybe around RTM or later).

Comment: @Elion "There could conceivably be a new product called ASP.NET 5 and Entity Framework 7", I have to say if you guys end up doing that, you will do a great job at confusing the crap out of people :P

Comment: @NickDeBeer the goal is never to confuse, but sometimes we confuse even ourselves :)

Comment: On the same vein: should we start removing "asp-net" from "asp-net-core" questions? *ASP.NET* is not the same as *ASP.NET Core*...

Comment: there is also [asp.net5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net5) ...

Comment: @poke would you mind converting your comment into an proper answer, if you still feel the same? Or let me know if you changed your mind and if so, to what.

Comment: @rene Done and expanded it a bit as well since we now have the full picture on this :) As for the `asp.net5` tag, we should probably just get a moderator remove that.

Answer (score 5):

As I explained before in the comments, the tags actually were renamed and synonyms were only added for the transition phase so that people that still remember the old names are directed towards the new names. That way, we avoided getting questions e.g. for ASP.NET 5 when the people were actually referring to ASP.NET Core.

As for the versioning of the tags, I am strongly against putting a version on every tag. Yes, there are situations where there are differences between specific framework versions that matter in a question. But the majority of questions can be answered without depending on a specific version. Not using a version also has the benefit of not putting us in a situation where we answered a question for an earlier version but don’t have an answer for the current version even though the original answer still applies.

The [general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271812/should-i-tag-questions-c11-if-they-refer-to-the-c11-standard-but-not-new-fea) [consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299598/should-there-generally-be-only-one-tag-for-a-language-rather-than-multiple-esp) on this is also that we should always use a version-less tag and *only* add a version-specific tag if there are really version-specific things within the question.

Considering this question is over three years old, we now have the chance to look back at how well this worked out:

- We consistently used [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) and [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) in all questions on these topics.
- We also avoided mixing [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) and [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) or [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) within a single question to make it clear that ASP.NET Core is a completely separate thing from ASP.NET (MVC). While there are many similarities, there are also a large number of very important differences that makes it hard to have questions cover both at the same time.
- For versioned tags we use [asp.net-core-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1.0), [asp.net-core-1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1.1), [asp.net-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-2.0), [asp.net-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-2.1), and [asp.net-core-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-2.2). These are mostly always used in combination with [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core).
- Versioned tags for EF Core are more rarely used.
- We still have synonyms for these tags but at this point we could consider removing them.

Looking forward, we fortunately know a bit about the roadmap for ASP.NET Core and .NET Core: .NET Core will unite with everything else as .NET 5 soon. At that point, we will probably have to think about on how we proceed since .NET 5 will be more similar to .NET Core than to .NET 4.x (which is the .NET Framework).

As for ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core, we don’t know whether they will really consider renaming the projects again. I really hope that they won’t bother to remove the “Core” part there too since that would just mean a lot more confusion than we had in the past. After all, EF 6 is also still a thing so EF Core 3 would have to jump quite a few versions to make the version number alone helpful in figuring this out (like they do with .NET Core there, skipping .NET Core 4).

But only time will tell; we unfortunately had quite a lot renames during the development of ASP.NET Core and related technologies, so I also wouldn’t be surprised if they came up with something new.

As for now, I don’t think we need to change anything about the status quo on the mentioned tags. I am personally quite involved with them and in my opinion it is working very well at the moment.

Comment: I'm calling it: it's going to be called .NET Unity.

Comment: Now that [.NET 5 is feature complete](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-8/) and we’re a few months away from it’s release, I imagine it’s a good time to start thinking about the questions you anticipated in this comment. [I’ve started a discussion thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400924/net-5-0-and-asp-net-5-0-tags), if you have a chance to weigh in.