# Remove [asp.net] from [asp.net-core] specific questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Many questions about ASP.NET Core are incorrectly tagged as ASP.NET. As [we already know](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx), these technologies are not the same, and worse, many of the questions are very specific to the framework and its APIs (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729845/how-to-turn-relative-route-into-a-relative-url).)

I've been removing [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tags from [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) questions willy-nilly but wonder what the community thinks about it.

*(This also applies to [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc).)*

Comment: related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315270/asp-net-5-ef7-tags-incorrectly-synonymized

Comment: @rene not really