# Burninate [asp.net-core-mvc6] and [asp.net-mvc6]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [asp.net-core-mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc6) and [asp.net-mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc6) should be burninated, as it's wrong and confusing at the same time.

When ASP.NET vNext (later renamed ASP.NET 5 and now named ASP.NET Core) was released in it's first betas, the MVC Framework part was versioned 6.0. During the current RC2 stage, all ASP.NET 5 packages got renamed to ASP.NET Core (which is also reflected in its namespace changes from `Microsoft.AspNet.*` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` also all versions got reset to 1.0.

This means that the tag [asp.net-core-mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc6) is not just wrong (ASP.NET Core never had a MVC versioned 6.0, only the previous ASP.NET 5) but also mixing two different naming schemes (the new asp.net-core with the old mvc6 name).

The second tag ([asp.net-mvc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc6)) is wrong in double sense: It first suggests the old ASP.NET framework and MVC6 which doesn't exist (since the one which was named MVC 6 got its version reset to 1.0 and called ASP.NET Core MVC) and even if a version comes in future, the current 93 question would still be about ASP.NET Core MVC, not about some yet to come version of the legacy ASP.NET MVC framework.

It neither makes sense to merge it with other tags (since its syntactically wrong) nor should further creation of the tag be allowed anymore (blacklist it, so it can't be created again).

The GitHub issue announcing the name and version change can be found on the ASP.NET Core Announcement issue tracker [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make them synonyms of some (presuming it exists) asp.net-core-mvc tag? The meaning behind them is clear; from your description it's just a natural result of things being renamed by MS.

Comment: similar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315270/578411

Answer (score -2):

I'm bumping this because it was resolved incorrectly and is now causing problems with creating actual proper synonyms. As @Tseng indicated, MVC 6 does not exist. Worse, it was made a synonym of [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc), *which also is not a thing that exists*. That tag should be made a synonym of [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core), but cannot be suggested as such because of this erroneous connection to [asp.net-mvc-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-6).

In short, both [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) and [asp.net-core-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-webapi) should be made synonyms of [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core).

[asp.net-mvc-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-6) should be burned entirely or also made a synonym of [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core), as well. I still believe it should be burned, though, because while it's unlikely that ASP.NET MVC will ever see a new version, if there was, it would be version 6, and that would be a totally unrelated thing to ASP.NET Core in any way.

Comment: Both *ASP.NET Core MVC* and *ASP.NET Core Web API* are frequently used in official documentation.

Comment: The ASP.NET Core name encompasses several technologies, two of which @Stijn mentions and also Razor Pages. Also, ASP.NET Core can actually run on .NET Framework versions compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 (although that will end in 3.0). See [The landing page for ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)